# Error creating a DevExpress controls for ASP.NET MVC empty project manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I need to use DevExpress controls for an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

So, I downloaded DevExpress Universal Edition something that has ASP.NET MVC controls.

Since I do not see a DevExpress ASP.NET MVC Empty project template, I am manually creating one following the instructions provided here:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163

However, when I start my application, I get this yellow screen of death that says:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required 
to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify 
your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Data.v12.2, 
Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


Line 39:       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 40:           <assemblies>
Line 41:               <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
Line 42:               <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
Line 43:               <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />


Source File: C:\Users\computer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\web.config    Line: 41

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = computer-VAIO\computer
LOG: DisplayName = DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/computer/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication5/MvcApplication5/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\computer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\computer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication5\MvcApplication5\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8847955d/8ce8b26b/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8847955d/8ce8b26b/DevExpress.Data.v12.2/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication5/MvcApplication5/bin/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication5/MvcApplication5/bin/DevExpress.Data.v12.2/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8847955d/8ce8b26b/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8847955d/8ce8b26b/DevExpress.Data.v12.2/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication5/MvcApplication5/bin/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/computer/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication5/MvcApplication5/bin/DevExpress.Data.v12.2/DevExpress.Data.v12.2.EXE.
```

It looks like the DLL versions I have and the ones mentioned on that page are different. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my project through their project converter which scans your references and web.config files and upgrades the entries to reflect the latest DLL's (if the ones you have are later than the ones you are pointing to in the web.config file), which was the case for me because I just copied the references from that page.

Answer (score -1):

It says you're missing the data assembly. You seem to be using an old version. Download the latest version as there is an empty project template in the DevExpress project wizard.

Also, contact the DevExpress support team and they can help you quicker.

Please take a look at this: 
[How to: Manually Register DevExpress Extensions to Start Using Them in an MVC Web Application](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Please take a look at the question carefully. I've provided that very link there.