# Error manually registering DevExpress controls in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

A few months ago, I'd downloaded v12.2 of DevExpress controls for a free trial. I got to [just set up a project briefly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906196/error-creating-a-devexpress-controls-for-asp-net-mvc-empty-project-manually) but never really got to use them then.

I am using them now after an extension of the trial period.

Since I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I do not see the DevExpress control templates and so I am using the instructions given here to manually register DevExpress with my ASP.NET MVC project:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163

I followed all the instructions to the letter. I even changed all version references from v13.1 to v12.2 and from 13.1.6.0 to 12.2.10.0.

But when I ran the project for the first time, I got the yellow screen of death with a run-time exception as depicted in the following picture.

[image]

Then I remembered that the DevExpress namespaces to be added to the `system.web -> pages -> namespaces` element must be done in the `Views/web.config` and not in the root web.config. This is not mentioned in their documentation but I remembered it from my trial and error attempts from the last time I'd used their controls.

Then, the first exception went away and now I get this exception.

[image]

I even ran the project through the converter tool in the Tools folder of the installation but have had no luck. I get the same runtime exception. I even wrote to their support but they seem not to respond at all.

Comment: I donno any IDEA about DevExpress, but Error says the Given TAg is not able to recogonize, either u comment and see will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the sample project if you'd like to try it out yourself. It's just a blank ASP.NET MVC project with changes in the web.config and some boilerplate code in the `Home/Index` view, copied from the example given in your online documentation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
        <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>

    <devExpress>
        <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" />
        <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
        <settings rightToLeft="false" />
        <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
    </devExpress>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication5-20130603185502;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Utils.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.SpellChecker.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Charts.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraCharts.v12.2.Web, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v12.2.Web, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.PivotGrid.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraScheduler.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
              <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
          <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" /></assemblies>
      </compilation>


    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />          
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

      <httpModules>
          <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
      </httpModules>
  </system.web>


  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
      </modules>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```